# Strange memory leak with analyze on text setting of UILabel

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel, iphone-sdk-4.3

When I `Product > Analyze` the clang analyzer gives me a memory leak I do not understand. It says that I am leaking in the second line something what was initialized in the first line of the following code

```
[[testView newScore] setText: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"+%d", addScore]];
[[testView newScore] setTextColor: [UIColor greenColor]];
```

As Instruments isn't working right now (I am using Xcode 4.1 with SDK 4.3) I can't investigate this leak any further.

Do you see why this could be a memory leak. The property `newScore` is defined like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *newScore;
```

and `testView` is a subclass of `UIView`.

Edit: Screenshot of the analyzer output:
[image]

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you post a screenshot of the analyzer output (i.e. the blue arrows pointing to the problematic control flow)?

---

Derp;  I missed the obvious.  Sorry.   The method is named `newScore` and the `new*` prefix indicates to the compiler that the object returned is +1 retain count.

Rename the method and all will be well.

Comment: Thank you. I have added a screenshot.